# Sharing directories in a Docker container both with a Dockerfile and after the container is running

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile

Sharing data between a running docker container and my host (on AWS) seems overly complicated. From the docker documentation it seems as if I need to specify volumes when I start the container.

I found this: https://github.com/synack/docker-rsync
But this watches recursively to copy only from the host machine to the docker container

I'm looking for a way to create (preferably in a `Dockerfile`) a folder visible on my host machine on AWS where I can `scp` files into that folder and they will be visible on my docker container. I am also looking for my docker image to be able to write to that folder so if the container is stopped I won't lose those files.

As a side note I already declared in my `Dockerfile` to 
    VOLUME /Training-master
but I don't know how to access it from my machine and when I stopped the container I lost the data.

Does anyone know how to do this or can they point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference for Windows users:

1) You can mount a host folder into a container by

```
docker run -ti -v C:\local_folder\:c:\container_folder container1
```

2) Alternatively, you can create a volume:

```
docker volume create --name temp_volume
```

See the absolute path of the volume by:

```
docker volume inspect temp_volume
```

The `mountpoint` is the absolute path of the volume. You can add/remove files from that path. Then you can mount it to the container by:

```
docker run -ti -v temp_volume:c:\tmploc container1
```

Notice that both host and container are Windows machines.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is provided by docker run time options. Documented here: http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume

At the end of it, its clearly mentioned

```
Note: The host directory is, by its nature, host-dependent. 
For this reason, you can’t mount a host directory from Dockerfile 
because built images should be portable. A host directory wouldn’t 
be available on all potential hosts.
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Raghav said a drive cannot be created and shared from a Dockerfile because of image portability.

But after you create the image you can run this command and this will create a shared folder between host and docker. Be careful because you can overview a directory in the docker container if it has the same name as an existing folder:

```
$ sudo docker run -itd -v /home/ubuntu/Sharing dockeruser/imageID:version bash
```

---

`/home/ubuntu/Sharing` -- Path to sharing folder on host computer

`/Share` -- Path to sharing folder in my container

`dockeruser/imageID:version` -- the name of your container

`-v` -- specifies you are creating a volume

`-d` -- daemonizes the containe, puts it in the background

`bash` -- the command for the container to execute